# clang-tidy fails with OpenCV code that compiles fine

Tags: c++, opencv, clang, ubuntu-20.04, clang-tidy

`clang-tidy` fails on this simple program:

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>

int main()
{
    cv::Mat m;
    m.at<const cv::Vec2i>(12, 34);

    return 0;
}
```

when run with

```sh
clang-tidy-13 test.cpp --  -I/usr/include/opencv4 -l/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_core.so
```

I get the following errors:

```
3 errors generated.
Error while processing /tmp/bla/test.cpp.
/usr/include/opencv4/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:1144:49: error: no member named 'channels' in 'cv::DataType<const cv::Vec<int, 2>>' [clang-diagnostic-error]
    CV_DbgAssert((unsigned)(i1 * DataType<_Tp>::channels) < (unsigned)(size.p[1] * channels()));
                                                ^
/tmp/bla/test.cpp:6:7: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'cv::Mat::at<const cv::Vec<int, 2>>' requested here
    m.at<const cv::Vec2i>(12, 34);
      ^
/usr/include/opencv4/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:1145:50: error: incomplete definition of type 'cv::traits::Depth<const cv::Vec<int, 2>>' [clang-diagnostic-error]
    CV_DbgAssert(CV_ELEM_SIZE1(traits::Depth<_Tp>::value) == elemSize1());
                                                 ^
/usr/include/opencv4/opencv2/core/cvdef.h:448:58: note: expanded from macro 'CV_ELEM_SIZE1'
#define CV_ELEM_SIZE1(type) ((0x28442211 >> CV_MAT_DEPTH(type)*4) & 15)
                                                         ^~~~
/usr/include/opencv4/opencv2/core/hal/interface.h:83:35: note: expanded from macro 'CV_MAT_DEPTH'
#define CV_MAT_DEPTH(flags)     ((flags) & CV_MAT_DEPTH_MASK)
                                  ^~~~~
/usr/include/opencv4/opencv2/core/base.hpp:372:40: note: expanded from macro 'CV_DbgAssert'
#  define CV_DbgAssert(expr) CV_Assert(expr)
                                       ^~~~
/usr/include/opencv4/opencv2/core/base.hpp:306:38: note: expanded from macro 'CV_Assert'
#define CV_Assert( expr ) do { if (!(expr)) abort(); } while (0)
                                     ^~~~
/tmp/bla/test.cpp:6:7: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'cv::Mat::at<const cv::Vec<int, 2>>' requested here
    m.at<const cv::Vec2i>(12, 34);
      ^
/usr/include/opencv4/opencv2/core/traits.hpp:382:31: error: no member named 'depth' in 'cv::DataType<const cv::Vec<int, 2>>' [clang-diagnostic-error]
{ enum { value = DataType<T>::depth }; };
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
/usr/include/opencv4/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:1145:40: note: in instantiation of template class 'cv::traits::Depth<const cv::Vec<int, 2>>' requested here
    CV_DbgAssert(CV_ELEM_SIZE1(traits::Depth<_Tp>::value) == elemSize1());
                                       ^
/tmp/bla/test.cpp:6:7: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'cv::Mat::at<const cv::Vec<int, 2>>' requested here
    m.at<const cv::Vec2i>(12, 34);
      ^
Found compiler error(s).
```

However, this file compiles and runs fine with both GCC and LLVM:

```
g++ -I/usr/include/opencv4  test.cpp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_core.so
clang++ -I/usr/include/opencv4  test.cpp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_core.so
```

I tried with GCC 10.3.0, LLVM 10.0.0 and 13.0.1 on Ubuntu 20.04 with OpenCV version 4.2.0.

Comment: Did you provide clang-tidy with the compilation database?

Comment: What if you get rid of that const?

Comment: @DanMašek Ah, then it works! Cood catch, that `const` doesn't really make sense there.

Comment: @sweenish In the original project yes, but here I tried to keep the example as minimal as I could make it.